# How do I run if, else in protractor?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor

I'm quite new to protractor. I want to see how I can execute if else statements in protractor.

For example:

```
describe 'Create a portal', ->
    it 'Create a Portal', ->

If (PortalisNew){
    element(By.css('.portal-col>.btn-primary')).click()
}

else{
    element(dropdownPortal).click()
    element(createPortal).click()
}
```

Comment: What is `PortalisNew`?

Answer (score 0):

you should be able to do an if else statement exactly like what you posted. I'm not sure where the variable PortalisNew gets set, but there is nothing special for an if else statement in protractor.

> ```
> if(PortalisNew){
>     element(By.css('.portal-col>.btn-primary')).click()
> }
> else{
>     element(dropdownPortal).click()
>     element(createPortal).click()
> }
> ```

if you need to do something to that PortalisNew variable before each it block or after each block it ***(and you're using jasmine)*** you can use [these](http://jasmine.github.io/2.1/introduction.html#section-9).

**example:** you may want to set the PortalisNew to false or true

```
  beforeEach(function() {
    // Do stuff
  });

  afterEach(function() {
    // Do stuff
  });
```

also if you need to do something before all it blocks or after all it blocks ***(and you're using jasmine)*** you can use [these](http://jasmine.github.io/2.1/introduction.html#section-10).

**example:** you may want to set the PortalisNew to false or true

```
  beforeAll(function() {
    // Do stuff
  });

  afterAll(function() {
    // Do stuff
  });
```